# Call Javascript Library after AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a main page that uses an AJAX call to expose content from a second page depending on user selection.  One of the elements that is generated by the second page is a dropdown list.  My dropdown lists are formatted using a Javascript library.

The issue I'm having is that, if I put the dropdown element on the main page, it renders with no issue at all.  However, if it's rendered by the second page (via AJAX), the dropdown doesn't render.  I feel like I need to somehow call the library again upon success but I'm honestly not sure.

Here's the AJAX code from my main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('input[name="location"]').click(function(){
        var data = {location : jQuery(this).val(), department : $('input[name="department"]:checked').val(), userID : 12345};
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/new-custom.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            async: 'true',
            success: function(result){
                jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show(); 
            }
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Here's the form element rendered on new-custom.php:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="field_20">Room Type</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="field_20" name="field_20">
        <option value="0" selected>Select an option</option>
        <option value="Double">Double</option>
        <option value="Queen">Queen</option>
        <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
        <option value="King">King</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here's the Javascript library that gets included on my main page:

```
<script src="/vendors/bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

Do I need to somehow execute the bootstrap-select.js library on the AJAX success function?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any JavaScript would have to be used after the HTML Elements exist, so in your `success` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the plugin on the newly added elements after you add them.

Change your code to :

```
        success: function(result){
            jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show().find('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); // initialize new elements
        }
```

Comment: for more plugin assign , how to achieve this ? like i have two more plugin assign with same way but it gives error to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most plugins, and all plugins that do immediate DOM manipulation, need to be initialized when elements exist. So if they are loaded by ajax then  you need to initialize them within the ajax callback after they are inserted in DOM

Can do something like:

```
jQuery('#div-custom')
      .html(result)
      .show()
      .find('.selectpicker')
      .selectPluginName(/* options*/);
```